# pure opengl locking mouse to screen center

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a problem when i lock the cursor to screen center with `SetCursorPos`

My problem is that it is stopping my camera from rotating, my camera works fine when i dont try and lock it. But it allows the mouse to drag off the screen when not in full screen.

```
void SetPosition(HWND hWnd, int x, int y)
{
    POINT pt;
    pt.x = x;
    pt.y = y;
    ClientToScreen(hWnd, &pt);
    SetCursorPos(pt.x, pt.y);
}

void COpenGLRenderer::OnMouseMove(int X, int Y)
{
    //This works fine if i dont set the mouse and i look around
    Camera.OnMouseMove(LastX - X, LastY - Y);

    if (LastX != X && LastY != Y)
        SetPosition(hWnd, this->Width / 2, this->Height / 2);

    LastX = X;
    LastY = Y;
}

void CCamera::OnMouseMove(int dx, int dy)
{
    float Sensitivity = 0.25f;
    Position -= Reference;

    if(dx != 0)
    {
        float DeltaX = (float)dx * Sensitivity;

        X = rotate(X, DeltaX, vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
        Y = rotate(Y, DeltaX, vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
        Z = rotate(Z, DeltaX, vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    }

    if(dy != 0)
    {
        float DeltaY = (float)dy * Sensitivity;

        Y = rotate(Y, DeltaY, X);
        Z = rotate(Z, DeltaY, X);

        if(Y.y < 0.0f)
        {
            Z = vec3(0.0f, Z.y > 0.0f ? 1.0f : -1.0f, 0.0f);
            Y = cross(Z, X);
        }
    }

    Position = Reference + Z * length(Position);

    CalculateViewMatrix();
}

void CCamera::CalculateViewMatrix()
{
    ViewMatrix = mat4x4(X.x, Y.x, Z.x, 0.0f, X.y, Y.y, Z.y, 0.0f, X.z, Y.z, Z.z, 0.0f, -dot(X, Position), -dot(Y, Position), -dot(Z, Position), 1.0f);
    ViewMatrixInverse = inverse(ViewMatrix);
    ViewProjectionMatrix = ProjectionMatrix * ViewMatrix;
    ViewProjectionMatrixInverse = ViewMatrixInverse * ProjectionMatrixInverse;
}
```

Comment: OpenGL does not have any functionality to control input devices or get informations from them. The Library/API you use to get the mouse events or to display the OpenGL window/context might have this functionality.

Comment: Welcome to SO! For your issue, try updating `LastX` and `LastY` with centreX, centreY. Anyhow, I think you should re-think your strategy. Setting programatically the cursor usually is not what user expects.

Comment: @Ripi2 is right, the X and Y values are obsolete if you move the cursor manually, so LastX and LastY need to be set to the center point. BTW Ripi2, the mouse pointer is hidden in these types of programs. It simulates locking the mouse to the application. Centering the mouse is just a convenient way of achieving that.

Comment: @Ripi2 what you mean by not what the user expects?

Comment: @Ripi2 to rotate the camera or an object, it can for sure be a good idea to hide and lock the curser until the mouse is released. Otherwise the user might reach the screen boundary with the curser before the intended rotation could be finishes, and then the rotation has to be stoped and the mouse as to be moved back again to continue rotation. How to set `x` and `y` depends on how the library handles locked cursors. GLFW for example continuously increase/decreases the x/y values, which could exceed the coordinates of the screen. Other libraries might use delta values.

Comment: @t.niese i changed it to `Camera.OnMouseMove(this->Width/2 - X, this->Height/2 - Y);` it seems to be working, But problem now is that the camera can jump around abit and move really fast if i move my mouse a tiny bit faster or move it around more.